# How to view a file's full history in P4V?

Tags: version-control, perforce, p4v

I've got a file that's been branched a few times and I would like to see it's full history in the History tab in P4V. Perforce has this data as I can do a timelapse view of the file with "Use branch history" and see all the previous versions of the file (as I'd expect). Is there an option somewhere in P4V to show this branch history, or history of a file across branches? It'd be rather useful.

Comment: Have you tried the Revision Graph? Right-click on the file in P4V and chose Revision Graph.

Comment: I have used the revision graph extensively. I specifically want the entire history in the History tab so it is instantly viewable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the upper right corner of the File History pane there's a "branch history" dropdown (it's the same icon as the "Show Branch History" button in Time-Lapse View).  Click that, and check the option to "Follow Branch Actions".  This will make File History follow the linear history of a file backward through "branch from" relationships, exactly as happens in Time-Lapse View when "Show Branch History" is enabled.

Comment: Is there a way to auto expand the collapsed parts of the history list?

Comment: I don't see a way to have it expanded by default, but Ctrl-A followed by + will expand everything in the pane you're looking at.